# Executing SFTP/FTP command in libcurl without actual transfer

Tags: curl, ftp, libcurl, sftp

Is it possible to execute SFTP command in libcurl without actual attempt of file transfer.

I set the command to execute (file deletion actually) using CURLOPT_QUOTE, but after executing the operation (and it executes successfully, file is deleted) curl is trying to upload or download file (based on CURLOPT_UPLOAD), so I get the CURLE_REMOTE_FILE_NOT_FOUND error error code.

What I tried so far - not setting the URL results in "malformed url error", setting CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY result in quote not executed as well. Is there any standard way?

```c
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

char temp[2000];
_snprintf(STRPARAM(temp),"%s://%s:%d/%s","sftp",m_url,m_port,a_ftpPath);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL,temp);
_snprintf(STRPARAM(temp),"%s:%s",m_name,m_pass);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, temp);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_PASSWORD);

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, NULL);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L);

struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
_snprintf(STRPARAM(temp),"rm /%s",a_ftpPath);
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, temp);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, headerlist); 

m_res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, NULL); 
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0L);
curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);

curl_global_cleanup();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CURLOPT_NOBODY](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTNOBODY) is the key for asking that no "body" is to get transferred.

Comment: With CURLOPT_NOBODY set libcurl quote is not executed as well, file remains intact

Comment: Looks like they think it's normal and quote without transfer is impossible :( Curl faq http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_run_custom Had to bypass the problem

Comment: 3.4 How do I tell curl to run custom FTP commands?
 You can tell curl to perform optional commands both before and/or after a file transfer. Study the -Q/--quote option. 

 Since curl is used for file transfers, you don't use curl to just perform FTP commands without transferring anything. Therefore you must always specify a URL to transfer to/from even when doing custom FTP commands.

Comment: "They" don't think that at all, you're mixing matters. *I* wrote that FAQ section you link to above.

Comment: Ok, but still CURLOPT_NOBODY doesn't works (executes quotes) for me. Without it everything works fine

Comment: Update - works if you specify CURLOPT_HEADER in addition to CURLOPT_NOBODY. Update faq if are able to please, it's a bit misleading

Comment: @elevener: if can you help us repeat that with an example program I think I'd consider it a bug and work to fix that instead of documenting it!

Comment: Added cutted out fragments from my code into question. This way (with CURLOPT_HEADER) works for me. Without it - returns CURLE_OK but file remains intact

Comment: On SFTP connection, when using `curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);` to delete a file without additional transfer, I always get a "Quote command returned error" code for the same quote command that works when not setting the nobody option. Interstingly this only occurs if I reuse the connection. If I create and initialize a new `CURL *` it works (but is very slow for sending commands iteratively). Any hint where I could search to fix the problem?

Comment: update: The quote is a `rm absolutepath/file` command and the command is successfully performed, so the file is deleted on the server, but still there is an error returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$sftp->delete('filename.remote'); // doesn't delete directories
// recursive delete
$sftp->delete('dirname.remote', true); // deletes a directory and all its contents
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, need SFTP for win32 c++ application so PHP libraries don't fit well