# libCurl: How to send a QUOTE without downloading a file or a directory-listing?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I want to delete a file on an sftp server. However I'm facing the problem, that the directory listing is always downloaded, which can be quite a lot of data on my server and takes a lot of time over UMTS.

Here's my code:

```
const char* url = "sftp://user:pw@ip/home/user/myDir/";
const char* quote = "rm /home/user/myDir/sampleFile.jpg";

// prepare the QUOTE
struct curl_slist *slist=NULL;
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, quote);

CURLcode res;
res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, slist);

res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, LIST_DIRECTORY_callback); // will download the directory listing => not wanted!
//res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL); // does not work
res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, NULL);

// perform the commands
res = curl_easy_perform(mCurl);

curl_slist_free_all(slist);
```

mCurl is a member object which was initialized only once to re-use the connection for other calls. This is initialization code:

```
mCurl = curl_easy_init();

CURLcode res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, 1); // 0 = no

mErrorBuffer.resize(CURL_ERROR_SIZE);
if(mErrorBuffer.size())
    mErrorBuffer[0] = 0;
res = curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, mErrorBuffer.data());
```

If I use the callback function with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` option, it will download the directory listing. If I set it to NULL instead, I get a libCurl error in  res`:`Failed writing received data to disk/application".

How can I send the quote without downloading the directory-listing? Do I have to set some option? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.
Maybe I could change the URL to a folder where there are fewer files, so the directory listing will be smaller, but I would prefer to not receive any unnecessary data here.

System is Windows 7 32 bit, libCurl compiled with a minGW.

Comment: ok... looks like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509709/executing-sftp-ftp-command-in-libcurl-without-actual-transfer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing SFTP/FTP command in libcurl without actual transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509709/executing-sftp-ftp-command-in-libcurl-without-actual-transfer)